# How to Use MotionLayout in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I want to use motionLayout for detail page of my app. It's important for me because It's my internship project and if I can manage to develop good app , I can get a job. Problem is that , I've tried this on new project just to see if it's working and it did but when I try to use it in fragment the animation is not working. I just want to slide my finger up and drag(disappear) image and restaurant name will remain on top and on bottom of that there will be details of that restaurant

---

fragment restaurant detail page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.RestaurantDetailPage">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:background="@drawable/title_layout_bg"
        tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_restaurant_detail_page_scene">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/detail_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                android:text="@string/kape_pi_restaurant"
                app:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semibold"
                app:lineHeight="26dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/restaurantDetailName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="32dp"
                android:text="Kafe Pi Restaurant"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semibold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment restaurant detail page motion scene end

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/endscene"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/title_layout_bg"
    tools:context=".view.RestaurantDetailPage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="32dp"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:text="Kafe Pi Restaurant"
            app:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semibold"
            app:lineHeight="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="32dp"
        android:text="Kafe Pi Restaurant"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semibold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit :** Scene

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@layout/fragment_restaurant_detail_page_motion_scene_end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@layout/fragment_restaurant_detail_page_motion_scene_start">
        <OnSwipe app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"/>
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

**Desired Motion of my App->**
[desired motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTH60.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to understand your problem. Some things you can do:

1. Provide more information xml/fragment_restaurant_detail_page_scene.xml
2. Isolate your animation in an example first. (create a new scratch project)

But based on limited information provided here:
MoionLayout uses a MotionScene file which should contain the s for the two layouts you are looking to create. It can only reference direct children.

It should also contain a  which describes the start and end and the gesture.

This is a quick 3 min overview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8c1RO3WgBA

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've tried my animation on new scratch project before implementing to main one. , It was working there. I'm happy to give you what kind of information you need. What should I provide ?

Comment: xml/fragment_restaurant_detail_page_scene.xml ?

Comment: I've added it. I would be grateful if you can help

Comment: MotionLayout is a layout that animates its views.
You are using the pattern where you extract the constraintsets from two layout files. 
They are being used to position the views that are children of the MotionLayout.

For this to work they should both be ConstrainLayouts containing the exact same ids. 
For example: if  "detail page motion scene end" has id's:
header_image,
content_layout,
title_layout,
textView2.
Then another layout needs to be a ConstraintLayout with those 4 ids
"GrandChildren" are not used.

MotionLayout does NOT switch between layouts